# show always an empty message until user enter a word

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have his method below to create a new bucket.

When the bucket name already exist I have a message "bucket name already exist".

But if user dont enter any word and click enter Im getting an errror, but I want to show again the message "Enter a bucket name" until user enter some word.

Do you know how can I verify also if user digit at least one word?

```
def createBucket():
    while True:
        c = boto.s3.connect_to_region(REGION)
        try:
            bucketname = raw_input("Enter bucket name ")
            bucket = c.create_bucket(bucketname)
        except S3CreateError:
            print "bucket name already exist"
            continue
        else:
            break
    return bucketname
```

Comment: What error do you get? You already use `try` and could catch that other error just like the one you already do catch.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well if it's let's say an "InvalidBucketnameError", then a second except-block with appropriate message would be trivial (he already has one), and even cover other invalid names as well.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What do you mean with "check the error type"?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There are many invalid names, for example "my bucket".

Comment: @StefanPochmann, can you link to the documentation that outlines the legal name format?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It doesn't. Closest thing it says is "Bucket names can contain lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens", which should really say "labels", not "names", and that they can *only* contain those things. I'm pretty sure some moron wrote that sentence. I just tested it in the S3 web console, btw, which told me "A bucket name in region cannot contain the character ' '."

Comment: @StefanPochmann, and what was the error? There seems to be some conflicting naming conventions depending on the region.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The error was only what I just wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for an empty string:

```
def createBucket():
    while True:
        c = boto.s3.connect_to_region(REGION)
        try:
            bucketname = raw_input("Enter bucket name ")
            if bucketname: # will be True for any non-empty string
                c.create_bucket(bucketname)
                break
            print("bucketname cannot be an empty string")
        except S3CreateError:
            print "bucket name already exist"
    return bucketname
```

You can `break` in the try if the data is valid, you don't need the else or continue. You may also want to move the `c = boto.s3.connect_to_region(REGION)` outside the while.